# VM error: revert in solidity while adding a uint8 to an int literal

Tags: solidity

I have this code:

```
function somePureFunction() public pure returns(uint256){
        uint8 temp = 255;
        return 2 + temp;
}
```

This code gives:

```
call to SimpleStorage.somePureFunction errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
```

But this works:

```
function somePureFunction() public pure returns(uint256){
    return 2 + 255;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In particular your problem refers to value about `temp` that you give to this variable.
When you declare a variable with datatype `uint8` you must to put inside it a value from 0 - 255 (255 excluded). For calculate the range of a specific uint, you can use this statement:

```
MaximumRange = 2*[numberOfBit]-1
```

Example:

Issue: I want know what is the range about uint32.

Expression = 2*32-1

Result = 0 - 4294967295

In your specific case, if you change this line:

```
uint8 temp = 255;
```

with this:

```
uint16 temp = 255;
```

it'll work successfully.

NOTE: You can change current datatype `temp` variable with other uint datatype like: uint16, uint32, uint64 and others. You must to keep in your mind the range of a single datatype and the value that you want to store inside the variable.